# How to refactor a large class with many methods that have single responsibility?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, optimization, refactoring

Searching for design patterns and better code optimization mostly pops up articles on inheritance and relationships between classes and tools on how to create class diagrams. I would like a little insight on how to, say split, a big class. Am working on a java program with a class that has crossed 1600 lines of code and about 20 methods. What it does is query for data from a data source and generate huge text file.

Now there are lots of data modification logic(for each logic I have created small methods) that goes on to queried data like:

-check data dates of users and perform changes
-append strings
-logic to check if a record needs to be ignored

and storing filtered data in Collection and generating text file. I don't think creating separate class for each small logic is good idea. Perhaps I can create separate *utility* class and stuff static methods into it? I can't post code for confidentiality issues. If someone can shed a little light to get me thinking in right direction that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: *I don't think creating separate class for each small logic is good idea*: that contradicts your willingness to obey to the single responsibility principle. Your question, without code, is much too vague. What I can say is that 1600 lines of code, and only 20 methods, means that each method, on average, is 80 lines long. That's huge.

Comment: actually 2-3 methods are very long because of many writer.append() and that's fine. But yeah may be I should re-consider what I consider as responsibility in my program. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 11):

The best thing you can do is forget what the code *does*, and think about what it *is*.

From the description you gave, you are "still" thinking about what your code is supposed to do. It queries a data source, checks dates, appends strings, filters, etc. This is not wrong for a functional or procedural approach, but not ideal for object-oriented code.

Try a little bit to forget what it supposed to do, and think about what "things" it is about. Are those things Accounts, Users, Machines, VirtualServers, etc.  What is that huge text file? Is it a UsageReport, a BalanceSheet, etc.

Once you got the "things", you can start thinking about what "responsibilities" you need to assign each of them. Again, "querying the database" is *not* a responsibility. You have to do something with the data you get, for example generating a UsageReport, *that* is a responsibility.

That is OO in a nutshell. A few more pointers: Try to avoid utilities, try to avoid getters, try to avoid setters even more. Try to avoid Services, Processor, Handler, Renderer and similar classes. Those are not "things", but usually procedures in disguise.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Yes, I did figured out some "responsibilities",and created separate class for, the most obvious, generating file. And as for the additional pointers, aren't getters and setters crucial for encapsulating data? Why to avoid it?

Comment: Getters and setters in fact de-encapsulate data (is that a word? :). You are giving out *your* data as a class, which is not OO. The alternative is to have others tell you what to do with the data without giving out the data. For example: Don't return a list of records, but offer a method to write them into a file, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should consider whether your initial premise is correct. The single responsibility principle states that a class should only have one reason to change.

In the case of the class you're describing, there are multiple responsibilities: querying a data source, filtering, string manipulation (presentation?), text file generation.

Each of these should be separated into its own class. This decouples the concerns and provides smaller more manageable code.

Comment: yeah I was fidgeting about what goes under methods and what qualifies for a separate class into itself. I guess that's something I will learn better with practice over time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**[SRP (Single Responsibility Principle)](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html)** suggests that we should have only one reason to change a class. i.e. a class should have only one single responsibility. So one class should do only one thing. So in an ideal object oriented environment, we would have classes for each of our work.

Ex:

Assume you are building a Calculator app with basic math support. Assume you have to implement **Summing two numbers** feature. In ideal way, you would have to do something like this.

```
public interface NumberMath{
    public float value();
}

public class Sum implements NumberMath{
    private float num1;
    private float num2;

    public Sum(float num1, float num2){
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

    @Overrride
    public float value(){
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

I think you already found that it will make our code much verbose. So practically no one will follow object orientation (or ***SRP***) in ideal way. Instead most of us would prefer one class containing methods for sum, subtract, division, multiplication etc. It makes our code less verbose.

But in your case ***1600 lines of code with 20 methods for 1 class can't be good***.

The best ways you can decompose your huge single class into multiple simple classes

- Identify independent methods.
- Combine similar small methods(behaviors) into a single class with a proper scope for that class, and a name that would properly define that scope.
- Try to completely avoid code duplication by adhering into method reuse instead.

Again it is somewhat difficult to provide a very specific answer for your problem since details are limited. Anyway hope this helps. :)

Comment: Supun, if it's an interface, you must use *implements* instead of *extends*. I'm sure that's a typo :)

Comment: @Jose4Linux, corrected, thank you

Comment: What if I have a case, where a class is a description of a property? (Think reflection, where the object represents some other object description). There are many methods like "hidden?", "sortable?", "editable?", etc. These are then used for code generation. How would you split such a class to smaller pieces? Some of these methods are required only for specific code output. Would you use a decorator (or something else) for these? But the decorator would need to access internal state of the wrapped object to know how to respond to these. Or should I just leave it as it is (big, many methods)?

Comment: (P.S. Of course this class is polymorphic, there are other variants, which respond differently. The decorator would split this logic to it, which means it would become harder for the maintainers to know which decorator should be used for what underlying property type.)

Comment: (P.P.S. "Tell, don't ask" principle could apply, but then I'd have to move the code generation parts to these "property-kind classes", which would violate SRP and be even more ugly. What do you think?)